# Why is fstream not working here (reading/writing in a file)?

Tags: c++, fstream

I've been having problems with fstream. The first time I'm writing and reading from a file it's working, but the second time it's not.

Here's the first time I'm doing it:

```cpp
std::ifstream stream(Window::FILE);
    std::string input;

    if (!stream.is_open())
        std::cout << "PROBLEM OPENING THE FILE\n";

    std::getline(stream, input); // checking if the file is empty
    if (input.empty()) {
        // if empty rewrite the information
        std::ofstream streamInput(Window::FILE);
        streamInput << "Digits\nDragGame: 0\nSoundGame: 0\nFallingGame: 0\n" 
            << "\nFigures\nDragGame: 1\nSoundGame: 0\nFallingGame: 0\n"
            << "\nColors\nColor: 0\n"; 
        streamInput.close();
    } else {
        // if not get it
        std::ifstream streamOutput(Window::FILE);
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> info;

        std::string input, header;
        std::string output;

        bool isHeader = true;
        while (std::getline(streamOutput, input)) {
            if (input == "") {
                isHeader = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (isHeader) {
                header = input;
                isHeader = false;

                continue;
            }
            bool flag = false;

            int level = 0;
            std::string word;
            for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {

                if (input[i] == ' ')
                    continue;

                if (input[i] == ':')
                    flag = true;
                else if (!flag)
                    word += input[i];
                else
                    level = level * 10 + (input[i] - '0');
            }
            Singleton::table.getInfo()[header].push_back(level);
        
        }
        streamOutput.close();
    }
    stream.close();
```

I'm saving my information in my table structure. I'm trying to put the new information if there is one in my main.cpp:

```cpp
std::ofstream streamInput(Window::FILE);
    std::ifstream g(Window::FILE);
    g.open(Window::FILE);

    g.clear();

    auto& k = Singleton::table.getInfo();
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> info;

    std::string input, header;
    std::string output;

    int game = 0;
    while (std::getline(g, input)) {
        if (input.empty() || k.find(input) != k.end()) {
            header = input;
            output += input + "\n";
            game = 0;
            continue;
        }
        bool flag = false;

        int level = 0;
        std::string word;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {

            if (input[i] == ' ')
                continue;

            if (input[i] == ':')
                flag = true;
            else if (!flag)
                word += input[i];
            else
                level = level * 10 + (input[i] - '0');
        }
        output += word + ":" + std::to_string(k[header][game++]);
    }
    streamInput.clear();

    streamInput << output;
```

But the file sometimes file doesn't load up.. I am sure that I'm passing the correct one, also when I use the .clear() method sometimes it's working and sometimes not. The fstream.is_open() returns false.

What could cause such problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried like 20 which were, but stackoverflow was trying to play smart and didn't allow me to send it. It was saying it wants better ones, so I tried typing random words and it worked out.. The moment it sent I managed to change it.

Comment: `std::getline(stream, input); // checking if the file is empty` - this is horrible! What if the first line of your input is empty? You'll rewrite its contents! Besides, the indentation of the code is horrible (first line looks like function declaration)

Comment: `std::ofstream streamInput(Window::FILE);` in the first snippet likely fails, since `stream` still holds the file open. Same with `std::ifstream streamOutput(Window::FILE);` In both cases, you don't check whether opening the file actually succeeded.

Comment: "The `fstream.is_open()` returns false." The text `fstream.is_open()` doesn't appear anywhere in the code shown.

Comment: In the second fragment, you are also trying to open the same file multiple times with different stream objects, as in `std::ofstream streamInput(Window::FILE); std::ifstream g(Window::FILE);`. That generally won't work. Open the file for reading, read from it, close it. Then open the file for writing, write to it, close it. Or else, use a single `fstream` object for both reading and writing, opening it once (but don't forget to seek to the correct position between reading and writing).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
std::ofstream streamInput(Window::FILE);
std::ifstream g(Window::FILE);
g.open(Window::FILE);
g.clear();
```

What you're doing is

1. open a file in for writing
2. open THE SAME file for reading, and associate it with a different stream.

Step 2 must fail. Clearing the fail flag is of no help. `g.clear()` is like a lipstick on a dead man's face. Any attempt to read anything through `g` is doomed to fail.

So, the solution is: do not try to associate two streams with the same file, especially when one of them wants to write. When you write, then write, and then close the stream. Only then can you open it for reading.

There's also a possibility to open a file for both reading and writing, `std::fstream`, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream , but I doubt it is what you are looking for. That is, don't use `fstream` just to cover a bad design of your handling the data streams. What you want to achieve almost certainly can be achieved with the standard `ifstream` and `ofstream`.

**EDIT**

Apparently it is possible to attach two streams to a file, but the result  is OS-dependent. If your program is run on my machine, the first instruction clears the file contents, so when `g` is opened, it can see only an empty file, hence it is in the `eof` state all the time, as if the two streams were forked.

See: [FIO24-C. Do not open a file that is already open](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO24-C.+Do+not+open+a+file+that+is+already+open)